# Prevent our app from auto-updating

Tags: ios

We would like users to backup relevant data on cloud and then update their app with new version.

Is there a way to prevent users from auto-updating our app? There are multiple benefits:

1. User has a choice whether or not to update
2. If there are any tasks to be performed before updating, the user can complete these before updating
3. User has a choice to read important information and instructions before updating.

Comment: Apps don't auto-update. Users have to manually update them from the App Store. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @c.cam108 sounds like someone from android new to ios?

Comment: Also sounds like you need a data migration strategy.

Comment: Just put it in the description or the update.

Answer (score 2):

Users have to manually update apps on iOS by installing them through the App Store. These updates are shown with release notes for that version, e.g.:

[image: App updates in App Store]

There is no way to execute any custom code during the update process, so you will have to handle any data migration the first time the app is launched after updating.

Comment: Our app is free and the services are configured in the cloud. The app is used to change & play the content. The user has an option to upload the content to cloud.

Comment: With auto-update the issue faced by the users is that they may not get a chance to upload all their content to cloud.

Comment: Updating an app doesn't affect the data stored by the app - nothing will be deleted when you update.